# Jquery Mobile: dynamically added list with nested item not opening inner list properly

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-mobile

Getting a strange issue. **It seems to be a bug.**

Am adding List items with Nested list, dynamically in a Jquery mobile List.
Now- clicking on the New List item- opens the New Nested List, but also its showing- previous nested list item *(the Last Nested List item before adding the New)*.

Here is the Fiddle-

[**http://jsfiddle.net/codenameavi/qSrfv/13/**](http://jsfiddle.net/codenameavi/qSrfv/13/)

[Use the Browser Back button to navigate between Nested and Main List in the fiddle]

Adding dynamically with this code-

```
$("#addBttn").click(function() {

      // adding a LI with Nested List in Main List
      var li = '<li data-icon="false" data-theme="a"><a>NEW ITEM</a>'

                 + '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="h" data-dividertheme="a">'
                     + '<li data-icon="false" data-theme="b">'
                     + '<a>NEW ITEM 1</a></li>'
                     + '<li data-icon="false" data-theme="b">'
                     + '<a>NEW ITEM 2</a></li>'          
                 + '</ul>'

               + '</li>';

    $("#newsListContent").append(li).trigger('create');
    $("#newsListContent").listview('refresh');
});
```

**EDIT**

Yes its a bug. Issue just reported- https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5098

The bug is there in latest version too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works :
**EDIT:**

```
var i=1;
$('#addBttn').click(function() {

     // adding a LI with Nested List in Main List
     var li = '<li data-icon="false" data-theme="a">NEW '+i+'</li>';
     $('#newsListContent').append(li);

    var ul = '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="h" data-dividertheme="a" id="ul_'+i+'">'
                     + '<li data-icon="false" data-theme="b">'
                     + 'NEW ITEM '+i+'</li>'
                     + '<li data-icon="false" data-theme="b">'
                     + 'NEW ITEM '+i+'</li>'          
                 + '</ul>';   
    $('#newsListContent li:last').append(ul).trigger('create');

    $('#newsListContent').listview('refresh');

    i++;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/prZ9a/1/

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. I tried ur code. But, adding more than 1 item dynamically, creating issue in nested page. Please take a look- 
http://jsfiddle.net/codenameavi/4jF7m/4/

Comment: you should give different IDs, I added `id="ul_'+i+'"`, see my solution

Comment: And I think it's better if you remove all the `<a></a>` and give different IDs to the three first items.

Comment: No. its not fixed with this solution- http://jsfiddle.net/codenameavi/4jF7m/5/ . Add multiple listItem and check- the new nested lists are conflicting. Why don't u fork the fiddle and test the code there!

Comment: see here : http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/prZ9a/1/  it works! without conflicting the new nested lists.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a bug.

jQM adds a index number to your li element child anchor tags that relate to the hidden page with the same data-url.

What is happening is the new li element has the same number as the last li element in the list which in turn causes the two pages to be show stacked on each other.

It's the FOOD element:

```
<a href="#list&amp;ui-page=newsListContent-0" class="ui-link-inherit">FOOD</a>
```

see the index 0 appended in the href, this is related to the hidden page:

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="list&amp;ui-page=newsListContent-0" data-theme="d" data-count-theme="c" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-d">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" class="ui-header ui-bar-b"
        role="banner">
        <div class="ui-title">FOOD</div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d"
            data-dividertheme="a"
            class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
            <li data-icon="false" data-theme="a"
                class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-a ui-corner-top">FOOD ITEM 1</li>
            <li data-icon="false" data-theme="a"
                class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-a">FOOD ITEM 2</li>
            <li data-icon="false" data-theme="a"
                class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-a ui-corner-bottom">FOOD
                ITEM 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the same index 0. Adding the new li element doesn't change the current li indices and duplicates the 0 index already used.

Here is the New li element ( The href points to the food li element as well )

```
<a class="ui-link ui-link-inherit" href="#list&amp;ui-page=newsListContent-0">NEW ITEM</a>
```

Here is the new hidden page:

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="list&amp;ui-page=newsListContent-0" data-theme="h" data-count-theme="c" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-h">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" class="ui-header ui-bar-b"
        role="banner">
        <div class="ui-title">NEW ITEM</div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="h"
            data-dividertheme="a"
            class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
            <li data-icon="false" data-theme="b"
                class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-b ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-corner-top"><div
                    class="ui-btn-inner ui-li ui-corner-top">
                    <div class="ui-btn-text">
                        <a class="ui-link-inherit">NEW ITEM 1</a>
                    </div>
                </div></li>
            <li data-icon="false" data-theme="b"
                class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-b ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-corner-bottom"><div
                    class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                    <div class="ui-btn-text">
                        <a class="ui-link-inherit">NEW ITEM 2</a>
                    </div>
                </div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Even if you update to the latest version it's still an issue:

- http://jsfiddle.net/qSrfv/16/

I've created a new Issue with jQM:

- https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5098

Looks like this has been an issues before but since you are adding the li elements dynamically I created a new issue

Comment: Thanks for reporting the bug & testing with latest version. So, i bypassed this issue by doing a checking on each main-List-item-click- which matches the List text with nested list page-heading, adds ui-page-active ONLY with that page. Will add a brief answer, about the procedure soon.